# Regex to match a 2-digit number or a 3 digit number

Tags: regex

I need to be able to check if a string contains either a 2 digit or a 4 digit number before a `.` (period).

For example, `39.` is good, and so is `3926.`, but `392.` is not.

I originally had `(^\\d{2,4).$)` but that allows between a 2 and a 4 digit number preceding a period.

I also tried `(^\\d{2}.|\\d{4}.$)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\.$
```

**This regex makes 2nd set of `\d{2}` optional** thus allowing to match `12.` or `1234.` but not `123.`.

Answer (score 2):

In the expression `(^\d{2}.|\d{4}.$)`, the dots match any character.

Try escaping them to make them match literal dots: `(^\d{2}\.|\d{4}\.$)`